# Как замаскировать значения в строке датарфейма?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, mask

Пусть дан датафрейм:

```
1) 2 3 3 2
2) 4 5 5 5
3) 0 9 8 1
```

Как получить такое:

```
1) 1 2 2 1
2) 1 2 2 2
3) 1 2 3 4
```

То есть, мы смотрим порядок и уникальность значения в строке и заменяем по этому принципу эти значения, как бы маскируя их. Обработка у нас построчная и независимая.

Comment: через это наверное: [len(set(v[pd.notna(v)].tolist())) for v in df[listofcols].values] с циклом из количества  = кол-во признаков - 1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Примените [pd.factorize()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html) к транспонированому DataFrame:

```
In [30]: df
Out[30]:
   a  b  c  d
0  2  3  3  2
1  4  5  5  5
2  0  9  8  1

In [31]: df.T.apply(lambda x: pd.factorize(x)[0]+1).T
Out[31]:
   a  b  c  d
0  1  2  2  1
1  1  2  2  2
2  1  2  3  4
```

Comment: обалдеть насколько лаконичное и красивое решение! спасибо, Максим!

Comment: @AlexandrKosolapov в качестве благодарности автору, можете не только поставить плюс, но и принять его ответ. Вам не сложно, коллеге приятно

Comment: передайте системным аналитикам портала, что я эту галочку увидел только сейчас))